# Toggle font awesome icon if active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am using font awesome to put arrows on an accordion sidebar menu. The extra `{liquid code}`is from Shopify. I am having a problem to properly toggle my `<i class="">` since the class can depend on if the link is active or not.

I am trying to have only the active or open `<i>` to be fa-angle-up and the others fa-angle-down.

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordian">
 <ul>{% for link in linklists.shop.links %}
  <li class="{% if link.active %}active{% endif %}">
   <h3>{{ link.title | escape }}
    <span><i class={% if link.active %}"fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"{% else %}"fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"{% endif %}></i></span>
   </h3>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: are you using jquery accordion?  if so you can just change the class in the activate function: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate rather than trying to create your own click event

Comment: what is the problem? console errors? or is the class not toggling?

Comment: I think you need to rename `accordian` to `accordion`

Comment: @Banzay: Pedantic, but unnecessary. At least it matches the id :)

Comment: I am using CSS to help toggle.
`#accordian ul ul {display: none;}` and  `#accordian li.active ul {display: block;}`

Comment: The `click(function(){` works fine, its just that if `<i>` is no longer active, it does not toggle back.

Comment: @AndrewP. please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question as currently it is unclear what your exact problem is and you haven't provided a snippet that replicates your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you want something like this. it's not the cleanest solution but it works as you want ( as i understood your question )

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        var ico = $(this).find('i')
        if( ico.hasClass("fa-angle-up") ) {
                  $(ico).removeClass().addClass("fa-angle-down")
        } else {
                $(ico).removeClass().addClass("fa-angle-up")    
        }
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.fa-angle-up { color:red;}
i { font-family:fontAwesome }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordian">
 <ul>{% for link in linklists.shop.links %}
  <li class="{% if link.active %}active{% endif %}">
   <h3>{{ link.title | escape }}
    <span><i class={% if link.active %}"fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"{% else %}"fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"{% endif %}></i></span>
   </h3>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't that clear but your solution helped me find mine. I just put the contents of the `else {` in the other `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I added an example here similar to what you want. It disables other `li` once you click on any other.

you can remove that functionality by removing first two lines of the click event function

I also altered some html for better snippet run. you can replace it easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
            $("#accordian ul li").removeClass("active");
            document.querySelector('.fa').className='fa fa-angle-up';
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
      $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
      if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
      {
       $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
     })
    });
```

```css
li{
  cursor:pointer;
}
li.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordian">
  <ul>
   <li class="listItems">
       <h3>link 1
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
       </h3>
      </li>
       <li class="listItems">
       <h3>link 2
        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
       </h3>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```